# How can I layer an element on top of a Grid within a Page, effectively ignoring the grid for some elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

Here is the code that I'm working with and an image which shows the result. This final product has the look that I'm going for, but I think that there must be a better way to do this.

```
<Page
x:Class="UIFollowAlong.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UIFollowAlong"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle"
           x:Key="ColorButton">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="RedButton"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Fill="Red"
               Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="YellowButton"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Fill="Yellow"
               Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="GreenButton"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Fill="Green"
               Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="BlueButton"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Fill="Blue"
               Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
    <Ellipse x:Name="CenterDot"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             Fill="Black"
             Width="50"
             Height="50"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: result]

The code in particular that I'm asking the question about is the Ellipse.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="CenterDot"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             Fill="Black"
             Width="50"
             Height="50"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

How can I align the ellipse to the center while ignoring the row and column definitions of the grid? By default, the ellipse goes to 0,0 and gets placed on top of the red rectangle in the top-most left-most grid position.

I tried to place within the page, rather than within the grid, but I think the page can only have one content property?

The picture I showed is exactly the result I wanted I'm just wondering if there is an alternative way to achieve this that does involve spanning multiple row and column definitions.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question to be honest.  It looks like you've achieved what you want, but aren't happy about the way you got there.  Why? Grids are for layout ...

Comment: I like to understand different ways of doing things, and different implementations of code to achieve the same effects while I'm learning new software and languages. Sometimes I'll go out of my way to do something in a harder weirder way just for the sake of knowing it works.  Also, doing a task in a different way, more outside of the box I often learn more about the underlying structure of the program. Yes I got the results I wanted from the code above, but I thought "Hm, there must be a better way to do this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have have multiple layers over the same area introduce one more Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <!--layer 0-->
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="RedButton"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Fill="Red"
                   Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="YellowButton"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Fill="Yellow"
                   Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="GreenButton"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Fill="Green"
                   Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="BlueButton"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Fill="Blue"
                   Style="{StaticResource ColorButton}"/>
    </Grid>

    <!--layer 1, covers layer 0-->
    <Ellipse x:Name="CenterDot"
             Fill="Black"
             Width="50"
             Height="50"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

Grid with White background and Ellipse are positioned in the same cell of the outer Grid.

To see how Ellipse can cover Rectangles - increase Ellipse size (Height/Width)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I'm looking for.